# When is a type registered by the type system in glib?

Tags: glib, vala, gobject

I'm currently working on a library, and ran into some strange inconsistencies in behaviour between my unit test code, and an actual app I'm basing on the code.

See, I'm trying to get a `Type` struct from the name of the class I want to instantiate, but I get nothing (e.g. Type is there, but `name()` produces `null`, `is_a()` fails, etc.)

However, if I make an instance of the type first, then try to get the Type based on name once more, it works just as I expected (which is probably why my unit tests work)

So I was wondering, when is a type registered by the type system and available via. `from_name(...)` ?

Does the type system only know it after it has been instantiated at run time? Is there another reason a class name wouldn't be recognized until an instance of the class has been instantiated? Should I use some other method of registration?

I'm coding in Vala if that makes any kind of a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type is first registered with the type system when its `get_type()` function is called. This is called in a number of places, basically whenever you need to get the `GType` for that type. Typically, it will first be called during `class_init` of the type, which happens during the first instance `init`.

So essentially you are right when you say “does the type system only know it after it has been instantiated at run time”, because that’s normally what happens. However, you can bring type registration forward by explicitly calling the `get_type()` function for a type early, and passing it to `g_type_ensure()`. For example, see what GLib does [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/2.62.0/gio/giomodule.c#L1211):

```
/* Initialize types from built-in "modules" */
g_type_ensure (g_null_settings_backend_get_type ());
g_type_ensure (g_memory_settings_backend_get_type ());
g_type_ensure (g_keyfile_settings_backend_get_type ());
…
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, even if it wasn't really what i wanted to hear. I'm not quite sure how i want to deal with this, though I might just do a switch case handling the instantiation instead of basing it on the namespace.

Comment: If you provide code examples I may be able to provide more concrete suggestions.